# Слово "разгильдяй"

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Каково происхождение слова "разгильдяй"? Оно родственно слову "гильдия"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, разгильдяями называли лиц, изгнанных из гильдий за нарушения устава или аморальное поведение. Более всего это касалось обвиненных в недобросовестной торговле купцов, поскольку других гильдий в России почти не было.

ЗЫ Чтобы не вводить в заблуждение. Про купцов - это факт, но я не утверждал, что на нем строится этимология. Очень возможно, что сближение вторично.

//-----------23.06.2014
Меня тут окончательно убедили, что прямая связь с гильдией невозможна просто хронологически, так что прошу считать эту версию народной этимологией.
Но что касается версии производного от "гулять", "гиль" и других - очень сомнительная фонетика: появление "Д" никак не объясняется продуктивными фонетическими законами.

Answer (score 4):

Разговорно-снисходительное слово, обозначающее  "нерадивый", "небрежный в делах", "разболтанный человек".
Исконно русское слово. Образовано, вероятно, от несохранившегося "гильдяй", являющегося производным от также утраченного "гильда", которое в свою очередь представляет собой образование от диалектного "гиль" - "смута, буйство,"путаница", первонач., возм., "расшевели-ка"? "Гиль" этимологически, по-видимому, связано с "гул", т. е. "гулять", "ничего не делать".

Comment: Слышал я подбную версию. Но очень много сомнительного. 
А кто это? Что-то не нашел я текста в этимологических словарях...

Плюсик мой, если что, дабы за наезд не восприняли.

Answer (score 4):

google:

разгильдяй разгильдя́й Образовано аналогично разгуля́й "увеселительное место", растрепа́й "растрепа, оборванец", т. е. от повел. формы (Преобр. II, 175). Возм., связано с гиль "путаница", первонач., возм., "расшевели-ка"? •• [Иначе, от тат. собств. Уразгильды, Уразгильдей, а также Разгильдей, Разгильдяй, объясняет это слово Попов (Из истории лексики языков Вост. Европы, Л., 1957, стр. 35). – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

wiktionary:

Происходит от неустановленной формы. Наиболее распространенные гипотезы: 1) суф.-преф. производное от гиль «смута, буйство путаница»; 2) от тат. собств. Уразгильды, Уразгильдей, а также Разгильдей, Разгильдяй. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера  с комментариями Трубачева